# Getting matches from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can i return the matches of two tables.

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `lost` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `firstName` int(100) NOT NULL,
    `lastName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `country` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    `color` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `location` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `airport` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `dateReported` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE `found` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `firstName` int(100) NOT NULL,
    `lastName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `country` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    `color` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `location` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `airport` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `dateReported` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now i want to create a query which selects all fields which have any matches on both tables.
And if possible another row which says how many matching fields it has per row.

Comment: these tables are essentially identical, except for the actual table name -- why not model both 'lost' and 'found' items as a single table with different 'status' or 'type' field to represent whether it was lost or found? simpler. your queries for then aggregating by one type or another are similarly easier.

Comment: Create a `view` with `inner join` on both the tables and `insert` into another table like `insert into matching select * from matching_view_v;`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood, is this what you want?

```
SELECT t.*,s.*,
       (t.firstName = s.firstName ) + 
       (t.lastName = s.lastName) +
       (t.country = s.country) +
       (t.address = s.address) +
       ..... as how_many_matches
FROM `lost` t
JOIN `found` s
 ON(t.id = s.id)
```

MySQL evaluates Boolean expressions as 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE , so can you just sum up the comparisons of the columns.

Note that both of your tables are exactly the same, this is not a recommended design. I advise you to add another column `TYPE` that will save `lost / found` and combine the two tables .